# Solutions to make a date viewer for a diary app in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui, uidatepicker

What would be solutions to make a date viewer for a diary app in SwiftUI?

I know there are `JBDatePicker` and `UIDatePicker` but is there any other solutions?

I want to make a simple diary app, which would be Google Calendar + texting (diary).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit short but in SwiftUI you can use DatePicker which is analogous to UIDatePicker.
There are tons of examples online how to implement it in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you can use something like:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var wakeUp = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            DatePicker("Please enter a date", selection: $wakeUp)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```